# JQuery - New name based off of old name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a form that can add extra fieldsets and inputs. I am trying to get the fieldsets and inputs to have an individual ids and names (such as fenceDescription2, fenceDescription3) but I can't figure out how to have the new element (for either the fieldset or the inputs) call on its own name so that it can add a new number to it. I got it to work with just one field but cant get the names to and the newNum correctly when I have multiple fieldsets. Ideally every time you clicked "add new fence" a clone of the elements would pop up underneath, each with a matching newNumber that corresponds to their order in the form (fenceHeight2 with postQuantity2 and postMeasurement2, and then 3 with 3, etc).  Any help explaining how this is done would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! Here is a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/3dnNP/1/

HTML :

```
    <fieldset id="fence">
    <div id="inputFence1" class="clonedInputFence">
        <fieldset id="fenceDescripton">
            <legend><strong>Fence Description</strong>

            </legend>Fence Description:
            <select name="fenceHeight" id="fenceHeight">
                <option value="select">Select Fence Height</option>
                <option value="6" id="fH6">6 Ft.</option>
                <option value="8" id="fH8">8 Ft.</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="post">
            <legend><strong>Post Type</strong>

            </legend>

            <label>Post Quantity:
                <input type="postQuantity" name="postQuantity" id="postQuantity" value="" />
            </label>
            <select name="postMeasurements" id="postMeasurements">
                <option value="select">Select Post Measurements</option>
                <option value="23/8 x .065 x 8" id="23/8 x .065 x 8">2 3/8 x .065 x 8</option>
                <option value="23/8 x .095 x 8" id="23/8 x .095 x 8">23/8 x .095 x 8</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAddFence" value="Add Another Fence" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDelFence" value="Remove Fence" />
    </div>
```

JS:

```
 //Dynamic Fence Input Fields
        $('#btnAddFence').click(function() {
                    var num     = $('.clonedInputFence').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem = $('#inputFence' + num).clone().attr('id', 'inputFence' + newNum);

                //Fieldset creation
                newElem.find('fieldset').attr('id', 'name' + newNum);

                //Fence Description 
                newElem.find($("select[name=fenceHeight]")).attr('id', 'fenceHeight' + newNum).attr('name', 'fenceHeight' + newNum);


                //Post Type
                newElem.find($(':input[name="postQuantity"]')).attr('id', 'postQuantity' + newNum).attr('name', 'postQuantity' + newNum);
                newElem.find($("select[name=postMeasurements]")).attr('id', 'postMeasurements' + newNum).attr('name', 'postMeasurements' + newNum);



                // insert the new element after the last "duplicable" input field
                $('#inputFence' + num).after(newElem);

                // enable the "remove" button

                $('#btnDelFence').removeAttr('disabled');

                // business rule: you can only add 5 names
                //if (newNum == 5)
                    //$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDelFence').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInputFence').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#inputFence' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

                // enable the "add" button
                //$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');
                $('#btnAddFence').removeAttr('disabled');

                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: so you want to have an input selected when you create the dropdown?

Comment: Yeah. The problem is that there are some fields (I didn't include everything because it would be too long) that go into equations for other fields. For example the number of needed rails is computed by the footage and fence height. So if they add a second fence I need to be able to have the computer be able to tell that the second footage and fence height is for the second rail quantity. Does that make sense? So far I can get a second fence to pop up but I can't figure out how to have the selectors, ids, or names be created in a way that every one is unique.

Comment: On my end the fiddle only adds a drop down selector instead of copying the entire fieldsets. When you said "input selected" I thought you meant an input selector and didn't want to correct you. My apologies. I am trying to have the fieldsets be copy and pasted underneath the existing fieldsets when you click "Add Another Fence" but, here is the part I can't figure out, I'm wanting each of the new inputs to have newNum as a prefix added to their name so that I can use them in an equation. So that the second "postQuantity" has an id of "postQuantity2" the third "postQuantity3".

Comment: The problem is that when you use `clone()` you have two elements with the same id `postQuantity` so when you try to `find()` the correct one, Jquery is not sure what you mean.